# ssl for mongodb hosted with IP address

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I am working on mongodb and hosted it on EC2 for production, now I want to add SSL/TLS, the SSL is working properly if I use the domain but I will use the IP to connect to MongoDB and I am not sure how to install the SSL for IP address. SSL for domain is not working when I try to connect DB with IP. Please guide me how I can do it.

Comment: Use the hostname instead of the IP. It is recommended my MongoDB and also preferred in certificate. Some certificate CA do not even permit IP Addresses in certificate SAN. Amazon may change the IP of their servers at any time.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks for the tip, I thought using IP is better as I have blocked public access to server. Should I use private DNS for SSL as there is not public IP or DNS for EC2?

Comment: I guess the certificate is created by Amazon, thus there is nothing you could change at it. For blocking public access it should not make any difference.